# Некорректно отображается сайт в панели разработчика

Tags: html, css

Столкнулась с такой проблемой - при адаптации сайта под другие экраны многие элементы либо занимают не полную ширину экрана, либо наоборот залезают за край. При этом везде прописано свойство width: 100%. Как можно это исправить? [image: Скриншот шапки]

Это стили шапки для стандартного размера экрана (1366px)

```
.header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    width: 100%;
}
.header > ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;

}
.header > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Это стили медиа-запросов:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header > ul > li {
        margin-right: 20px !important;
        padding: 0 0px;
    }
    .header > ul {
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Вот еще пример того что происходит с сайтом. У фона 100% ширина:
[image: Неправильное отображение]

Вот так выглядит оригинал:
[image: Оригинал сайта]

Сайт всегда отображается по разному. Причем я код совсем не меняю. Максимум обновляю страницу и результат всегда может быть разный

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый пример. Этого кода недостаточно, чтобы понять, что у Вас не так

Comment: Пока готовила скриншоты, сайт начал отображаться нормально. Я не понимаю, что происходить. Как только я открыла панель разработчика, шапка занимала не всю ширину. Потом я закрыла и заново открыла панель разработчика. Сайт начал наоборот залезать за края. А теперь он отображается нормально. В чем здесь может быть проблема? Попробую приложить скриншоты, как будет сайт выглядеть, если я код менять не буду

Comment: Может быть такое, что экран в dvetools масштабируется сам по себе. Не всегда, но очень редко такой баг ловил. Помогает просто приведение к 100% (Ctrl+0), это чисто локальная проблема, на устройствах обычно всё ок. Возможно, не выставлена мета-информация (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`), и браузер не знает как масштабироваться.

Comment: `Пока готовила скриншоты, сайт начал отображаться нормально. Я не понимаю, что происходить.` если скрипты\стили стандартные берете из CDN(указывая оригинальный линк), наверняка просто они подгружаются долго. скачайте все стили вручную и залейте на свой хост. `Сайт начал наоборот залезать за края` наверняка кривая js пародия на @media тому виной, или опять же не все правила подгрузились. попробуйте реализовать адаптивность без js и препроцессоров.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> у меня прописан. Возможно реально проблемы с масштабированием, но их можно как-то исправить? Или только 100% масштабирования надо выставлять?

Comment: У меня сайт в локальной сети на компьютере, с интернета ничего не подгружается